# upgrade database table in new version without losing old version data in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a database that I built in SQLite, and it works fine. I wanted to upgrade the database and add a new column.

When I click RUN they gives me this :

[image: Photo]

This my code to upgrade the database but they don't work without uninstall old version app.

```
static class DBinfo extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String dataBase_Name = "dbase";
    private static final String tableName = "mytable";
    private static final int dataBase_Version = 2;
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String name = "name";
    private static final String nrx = "nrx";
    private static final String dane = "dane";
    private static final String mang = "mang";
    private static final String sal = "sal";
    private static final String roj = "roj";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tableName;
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+tableName+
            "("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+name+" VARCHAR(255), "+nrx+" VARCHAR(255), "+dane+" VARCHAR(255), "+mang+" VARCHAR(255), "+sal+" VARCHAR(255),"+roj+" VARCHAR(255));";
    private Context context;


    public DBinfo(Context context) {
        super(context, dataBase_Name, null, dataBase_Version);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try{
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
           // Toast.makeText(context,"table created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (SQLException e){
         //   Toast.makeText(context,"due to: "+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (newVersion > oldVersion){
             db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " +tableName+ " ADD COLUMN " +roj+ " TEXT");
        }
    }
 }
```

The method `OnUpgrade` code cannot work, all time they gives me the first photo.

I searched too long in internet but I didn't solved it.

Answer (score 0):

That message has nothing to do with your database or changes thereto. It means you are trying to install an APK with the same package as an existing APK, but with a different signature.  Your new app isn't even getting installed.

I can't say why your signature is different, but consider what changes you may have made to your build system or the certificate you are using to sign your builds.

Are you trying to install a debug-signed APK on top of a release-signed APK?

Comment: No, I changed VersionCode too.

Comment: It's not a problem with the version code. The problem is with the signature as I said.

Comment: i changed the key too, same thing.

Comment: They won't solve it. You need to solve it. Whatever cert was used to sign the app currently installed is not the same as the one you are using to sign your dev app. No one here is going to be able to help since we don't have access to your development environment or your keys.